# Issue with Ext XTemplate

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to create a XTemplate to show the one-many relationship display for each item in dataview.

I want to display the TransactionType as Header of the list item and i have to loop through the ActionList for that ActionSummary and show each Action item name.

But below code fails.

**Models**

Action Model here

```
Ext.define('MyMobile.model.ActionModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        { name: 'Action', type: 'string' },            
        { name: 'Count', type: 'int' },            
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'CurrentStatus', type: 'string' }
    ]
}
});
```

Action Summary Model

```
Ext.define('MyMobile.model.ActionSummaryModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'TransactionType', type: 'string' }

    ]
    ,
    hasMany: {
        model: 'MyMobile.model.ActionModel',
        name: 'ActionList'
    }
}
});
```

**Store**

Ext.define('MyMobile.store.ActionSummaryStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

```
config: {
    model: 'MyMobile.model.ActionSummaryModel',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'home/GetActionSummary',
        method: 'GET',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
}
});
```

**View**

```
Ext.define('MyMobile.view.ActionListView', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype: 'actionsummary',
id: 'actionsummaryList',

config: {
    title: 'Actions',

    store: 'ActionSummaryStore',
    emptyText: 'Loading action items...',
    itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">',
                                            '<div><p class="action-text">{TransactionType}</p>',
                                                  '<tpl for="ActionList"><tpl for=".">',       
                                                        '<p>{Action}</p>',  
                                                         '<span class="action-count">Count:{Count}</span><br>',
                                                         '<span class="action-status">Current Status: {CurrentStatus}</span>',
                                                    '</tpl></tpl>',          
                                             '</div>',
                                           '</tpl>'

                       )
 }
 });
```

**JSON** JSON is array of summary from server

```
[{"Id":1,"TransactionType":"Transaction 1","ActionList":[{"Id":1,"Count":4,"Action":"Action Item 1","CurrentStatus":"Open"},{"Id":2,"Count":14,"Action":"Action Item 3","CurrentStatus":"Open"},{"Id":3,"Count":44,"Action":"Action Item 5","CurrentStatus":"Close"}]}]
```

**If i hard code this JSON data instead of store it is working.**

```
Ext.define('WorksMobile.view.ActionListView', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype: 'actionsummary',
id: 'actionsummaryList',

config: {
    title: 'Actions',


    data:[{"Id":1,"TransactionType":"Transaction 1","ActionList":[{"Id":1,"Count":4,"Action":"Action Item 1","CurrentStatus":"Open"},{"Id":2,"Count":14,"Action":"Action Item 3","CurrentStatus":"Open"},{"Id":3,"Count":44,"Action":"Action Item 5","CurrentStatus":"Close"}]}],

    emptyText: 'Loading action items...',
    itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">',
                                            '<div><p class="action-text">{TransactionType}</p>',
                                                  '<tpl for="ActionList"><tpl for=".">',  
                                                        '<p>{Action}</p>',  
                                                         '<span class="action-count">Count:{Count}</span><br>',
                                                         '<span class="action-status">Current Status: {CurrentStatus}</span>',
                                                    '</tpl></tpl>',          
                                             '</div>',
                                           '</tpl>'

                       )
}
});
```

I have no idea why the above XTemplate not working with JSON store. It shows only Transaction Type, mean header and not the nested items details. Please help on this.

**Edit:** After some time i realized Store is not loading with relationships. It is not showing ActionList under each ActionSummary. Is there any mapping issue?

**Edit 2**
I removed the hasMany mappings in ActionSummaryModel and added a field { name: 'ActionList', type: 'auto' } then it is working. But i would like to do it with relationships with **hasMany** and **belongsTo**. Your help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I will list down all the steps to make your code working as following:

Firstly, add `autoLoad` in your store to automatically load the related store from a remote source when instantiated

```
model: 'MyMobile.model.ActionSummaryModel',
autoLoad: true
```

Secondly, you need to use `associationKey` which is the name of the property in the data to read the association from instead of `name` in your `hasMany` association:

```
hasMany: {
    model: 'MyMobile.model.ActionModel',
    associationKey: 'ActionList'
}
```

Finally, in your view you need to make some changes in your `tpl` by changing:

```
<tpl for="ActionList">
```

to the associated model name in plural:

```
<tpl for="actionmodels">
```

By the way, remember to include all your corresponding view, store and model in your app.js to make it works. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution for this that works with the models and associations?